# Registering a Custom href Protocol on Windows Mobile in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web, windows-10-mobile

I am developing a web-based mobile application, My application has a button that takes the user to the dialer where a USSD code is ready for the user to dial. This works fine on Android Devices and iOS devices.

```html
<a href="tel:*222*263000000000#">Trigger USSD</a>
```

On Windows 10 Mobile that link triggers the People App or the Skype App. If this was a native app I know I could register a URI protocol to trigger the dialer. Is there a workaround in JavaScript I can use to target the dialer (Or Phone App) specifically such as registering a custom href protocol maybe.

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, like you said, the app itself is responsible for registering custom URI or catch the intent of existing URI, even from the browser. On Android, the user can choose from all the application that catch the intent what application he wants to use.

I think that the answer should be what kind of protocol the Phone app uses, then use this protocol in order to 'target' the dialer.

Comment: The default protocol for the dialer is the href="tel:+263000000" , this default does not have the  same behavior on Windows 10 Mobile. Is there a way to create protocols from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no protocol of Phone app being exposed, but you can use the [PhoneCallManager.showPhoneCallUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.calls.phonecallmanager) method to launch the built-in phone call UI with the specified phone number and display name.

`Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.PhoneCallManager.showPhoneCallUI(phoneNumber, displayName);`

Comment: I would be very surprised if the UWP APIs could be used from within Edge.

Comment: Creating URI protocols is a challenge in this case because I am attempting to do it from Edge in JavaScript. If I was developing this in say C#, I would use that approach